# How to change the colour of button according to number of characters in input field in react.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

if number of characters in input field is less than 10
button should be disabled

if number of characters in input field is less than 20
background colour of button should be red

if number of characters in input field is more than 20
background colour of button should be green

```
export default function App() {
const [input, setInput] = useState("")

let inputLength;
const handleChange = (e) => {
setInput(e.target.value)
inputLength = e.target.value.length
console.log(inputLength)
}
return (
<div className="App">
 <h1>hello</h1>
 <button>Submit</button>
 <input value = {input} onChange = {handleChange}/>
</div>
);
}
```

Comment: you'd use "code" - what code have you tried?

Comment: updated code in the question

Comment: where are you testing for the number of characters in the input and attempting to change the background colour of the button?

Comment: i don't know how to change the background colour of button

Comment: `element.style.backgroundColor` is one way - or set a `class` and use CSS stylesheets to do it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this code will help you.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");

  let inputLength;
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
    if (e.target.value.length > 10 && e.target.value.length < 20) {
      setColor("red");
    }
    if (e.target.value.length > 20) {
      setColor("green");
    }
    inputLength = e.target.value.length;
    console.log(inputLength);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <button
        style={{ background: color ? color : "" }}
        disabled={input.length < 10}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
      <input value={input} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also here is demo https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-julien-vu6vkt?file=/src/App.js:0-769

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the style of the button according to your input length like in my example with getButtonStyle. If you don't know how to change styles in react, please read this for more information on how it works: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp
Also if you feel like optimizing things you can read about useCallBack: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

```js
export default App = () => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState("");

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setInput(e.target.value);
    };

    const getButtonStyle = () => {
        const len = input.length;
        if (len <= 10) {
            return { disabled: true };
        } else if (len <= 20) {
            return { backgroundColor: "red" };
        }

        return { backgroundColor: "green" };
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>hello</h1>
            <button style={getButtonStyle()}>Submit</button>
            <input value={input} onChange={handleChange} />
        </div>
    );
};
```